# Arduino/C++ adjusting Long Millis () in loop

Tags: c++, loops, arduino, long-integer

So I have made a simple Arduino circuit for practice. I am able to start and stop the loop at any moment via a button. Now I want to make some sick led light sequences.

My initial thought is changing the `delay_led1` function at the end of the loop. That way I am able to change the sequence when the loop ends.

I tried to do this with: `interval_led1 + 300` (marked in my code with alot of /////////) at the end of the loop, but this doens't work.

How could I add milliseconds to the `interval_led1` function via the loop?

```cpp
const int led1 = 13;
const int led2 = 8;
const int led3 = 5;
const int button = 10;

int ledState_led1 = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
int ledState_led2 = LOW;
int ledState_led3 = LOW;

// Generally, you should use "unsigned long" for variables that hold time
// The value will quickly become too large for an int to store
unsigned long previousMillis_led1 = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
unsigned long previousMillis_led2 = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis_led3 = 0;

long interval_led1 = 500;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)
long interval_led2 = 600;
long interval_led3 = 700;

boolean buttonstate = false;

void setup() {

    pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the difference
    // between the current time and last time you blinked the LED is bigger than
    // the interval at which you want to blink the LED.
    unsigned long currentMillis_led1 = millis();
    unsigned long currentMillis_led2 = millis();
    unsigned long currentMillis_led3 = millis();

    bool current_state = digitalRead(button);
    bool prev_buttonstate= false;

    if(current_state==HIGH && current_state != prev_buttonstate) {  
        buttonstate = !buttonstate;    //reverse buttonstate value
    }
    prev_buttonstate = current_state;

    if(buttonstate==true)
        if (currentMillis_led1 - previousMillis_led1 >= interval_led1) {
            previousMillis_led1 = currentMillis_led1;
            if (ledState_led1 == LOW) {
                ledState_led1 = HIGH;
            } else {
                ledState_led1 = LOW;
            }
            digitalWrite(led1, ledState_led1);
            ////////interval_led1 + int(3000); ///////////////////
        }

    if(buttonstate==true)    
        if (currentMillis_led2 - previousMillis_led2 >= interval_led2) {
            previousMillis_led2 = currentMillis_led2;
            if (ledState_led2 == LOW) {
                ledState_led2 = HIGH;
            } else {
                ledState_led2 = LOW;
            }
            digitalWrite(led2, ledState_led2);
        }

    if(buttonstate==true)
        if (currentMillis_led3 - previousMillis_led3 >= interval_led3) {
            previousMillis_led3 = currentMillis_led3;
            if (ledState_led3 == LOW) {
                ledState_led3 = HIGH;
            } else {
                ledState_led3 = LOW;
            }
            digitalWrite(led3, ledState_led3);
        }
}
```

Comment: What sick pattern are you trying to make? The line `interval_led1 + int(3000);` will add those two numbers and discard the result. The compiler is probably optimizing this out.

Comment: What's the purpose of those three identical currentMillis_led<x> variables? local `bool prev_buttonstate=false;` looks weird, too.Title and explanation text are hard to understand or even guess, for me, at least?

Comment: Your code as written *should* work. What doesn't work about it? What is your observed output?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have:

Interval_led = interval_led1 + 3000;

Where you actually assign a new value to that variable?